# jScrollPane: Remove scrollbar gutter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'd like to have the scrollbar place over the content instead of forcing a gutter beside it.

In the attached image you can see what it currently does with the red scroll bar...it creates a vertical gutter that pushes the content to the side.

But what I want to do is what's on the bottom...have the scrollbar positioned over the content.

I've tried absolutely positioning `.jspVerticalBar` but I haven't been able to get rid of the gutter.

[image]

EDIT: Here's the jsFiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8Mebt/3/ -- As you can see, there's still a gap on the far right and the "selected" state of the item doesn't extend all the way over as I want it to.

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle or other example of this in action? This way it will be much easier to figure out how to help.

Comment: I ca solve it if u provide us a fiddle... :)

Comment: On my computer, I'm not able to scroll the jScrollPane page using my mouse wheel at all. Is this something you're aware of?

Comment: @Tobias: I haven't cross-browser tested all the javascript yet...and since I don't know what "your computer" is running, I can't tell you what the problem may be. It's working fine on mine though. :)

Comment: @Shpigford Sorry, I should have said - Safari 5.0.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.jspVerticalBar` is already absolutely positioned. Set its `right` property to what you want, and also set

```
.jspHorizontalBar, .jspVerticalBar, .jspTrack {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

so that the background of the gutter (*track as is it called in jscrollpane*) is transparent..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/DsDQP/

---

**Update**

After the comments (*including a jsfiddle*) here is my workaround..

Set  the `verticalGutter` setting to `0` and recalculate the width of the jspPane to include the jspTrack width..

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({verticalGutter:0});
$('.jspPane').css({width:'+=' + $('.jspTrack').width()});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/DsDQP/8/

*The recalculation needs to be called after each reinitialization..*

> This is needed because the width of the jspPane (*the content*) is being added through javascript by calculating the container width and removing the `verticalGutter` and the `.jspTrack` width. You can alternatively redefine the width with CSS and use the `!important` directive to override the width added through javascript as ***@Evgeny*** mentions in the comments.

Comment: I dont think he need to make it TRANSPARENT.. even if its transparent, the content will be pushed sidewards.. He want to remove the track and remove that space...

Comment: @blasteralfred: Look at the demo. It does exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't do what I'm saying. See my update: http://jsfiddle.net/DsDQP/3/ There's still a gutter on the right.

Comment: I see there's no gutter in those examples, but I can't figure out why in my example I can't get rid of the gutter (based on my HTML/CSS). http://jsfiddle.net/8Mebt/8/

Comment: @Shpigford, you need to call it after the `jScrollPane` function. and also after each `.reinitialise()`.. updated demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8Mebt/9/

Comment: Ah perfect. This works great! Assuming no one submits some magically better answer, I'll award the bounty when Stack Overflow lets me in 22 hours. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can put a negative `verticalGutter` value at the jScrollPane initialization and it will do the trick, with no additional actions required.

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({verticalGutter:-100})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DsDQP/50/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it this way.....

```
    //Should it (the #parentContainer) have had a "scroll-pane" class

        $('#parentContainer').jScrollPane()

    $.each(data, function(i, value) {

//Detach scrolling capabilities
        $('#parentContainer').jScrollPaneRemove();

        $('<div/>',{
        class:'anyClass',
        id:'anyId'
        })
        .appendTo(#childContainer);

//Return back Scrolling capabilities to the parent container    
        $('#parentContainer').jScrollPane();            


        ///-> Loop Ends
                });
```

With this, the scrolling capabilities are renewed every time a loop is made....hence the ScrollBar's length will grow or shrink depending on the size of data store in the child container.

Hope that helps....

Ebest